# Sending client's Exception to WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have this scenario:

An MVC application working with a WCF service, I'm trying to add the Log Error feature for the MVC application.

MVC application doesn't have direct access to Database, WCF service does.

Since the MVC application doesn't have access to the Database, I need to send the Exception (whenever it occurs) to the WCF then it will be saved in the Database.

In the OnException() method for each controller, I'm sending the exception to the WCF, but it fails to get it.

This is my Controller's code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string myText = null;
        myText = myText.Substring(0, 2);

        return View();
    }

    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            Exception ex = filterContext.Exception;
            Service1Client wsClient = new Service1Client();
           //I try to send exception to the WCF
            wsClient.SaveExceptionToElmah(ex);

        }
    }
```

This is the way my WCF method is implemented:

```
public void SaveExceptionToElmah(MyException error)
    {
        //this will be managed by Elmah log error feature
        throw error.myEx;
    }
```

I've found something about adding [knownType(typeof(....))] attribute to my class in the WCF, but it didn't work.

How can I implement my WCF method in order to get the exception correctly

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can see is that you are passing an `Exception` type but the signature in your WCF method seems to be a custom type of `MyException` try changing the type you are passing or the type you expect to match

Comment: Actually I found the solution for this problem, I found a link in one of the answers to a similar problem, what I did is to convert the exception to an array of bytes then I serialize the array and it's sent to the WCF.In the WCF  I'm expecting the same type of array, after that the array is transformed to an exception, In that way I can get an manipulate the same exception that was thrown in the client side.

Comment: Do you have a link to that answer? I'd love to see how they did it.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Marco, I don't find the link :(